# Position scrollbar to be contained inside the element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customise the scrollbar so it is contained inside the element i.e. , it should not occupy it's own space.Something like the following:

[image]

Following is the code I tried:

```css
div.ex1 {
  /* background-color: lightblue; */
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
  height: 18px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 60px;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background: red">

  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7mev1j6/6/) link.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can try http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: @Zuber I really would like to do this without a library.

Comment: @johnnash The scrollbar in the fiddle is already contained inside the div. What is your requirement?

Comment: but that may affect in cross browser compatibility @johnnash

Comment: I'd advise against doing so. This is not a feature CSS standard includes per se and history has shown that any vendor specific scrollbar styles caused incompatibilities later. And implementing such features on your own instead of using system/browser scrollbars may cause problems in future browsers as you never know what crazy kind of technology will be in use tomorrow (e.g. popularization of touchscreens has broken many of such features in past).

TL;DR: Do not alter default behavior of scrollbars. It is asking for problems.

Comment: @Arex In jsfiddle output, you can see that it occupies it's own space.I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Below I placed approach I would use. I wrapped `ex1` div in `ex0` div, which has `padding 0 5px 0 0`. Trick is to increase the distance between `ex1` and wrapping element. You can adjust precise values.

My solution is below, but first thing first...

#### Support

Please have in mind, that [`::-webkit-scrollbar` selectors are supported only by webkit-based browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar).

> ::-webkit-scrollbar is only available in WebKit-based browsers (e.g., Safari, all browsers on iOS, and others).

Morover...

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

#### Key part

```
div.ex0 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

div.ex1 {
  /* background-color: lightblue; */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 110px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
div.ex0 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

div.ex1 {
  /* background-color: lightblue; */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 110px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
  height: 18px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 60px;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex0">
  <div class="ex1">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background: red">

    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</div>
```